# how i integrate payumoney in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, payumoney

I am totally new in codeigniter.
I'm trying to integrate PayuMoney in codeigniter. 
Can anyone guide me how to do that?

I want to send data filling the form I already insert data in to the database.

Payment method can any one help me to do payment using PayuMoney.

Comment: Vidhi Patel Please [check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912322/payumoney-codeiginiter-integration) For your requirements

Comment: for More Guidance you can watch it [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_tE37eE1_g](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_tE37eE1_g)

Comment: thanks Jaykumar Gondaliya i will check both of link

Comment: have you Got the answer?
if you cant please share you Research code here

Comment: maybe this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058403/how-to-integrate-payumoney-payment-gateway-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Here simple example for PayUmoney Integration

[PayUmoney Payment Gateway In Codeigniter](http://www.pagequeen.com/how-to-integrate-payumoney-payment-gateway-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: The tutorial is for php and NOT Codeigniter.